# Temperature Errors, Java Basics

Tags: java

```
public class Temperature {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double tempf = 98.6;
        double tempc = 0.0+tempc;
        ftoc(tempf, tempc);
        System.out.println("Body temp in C is: " + tempc);
    }

    // converts Fahrenheit temperatures to Celsius
    public static double ftoc(double tempf, double tempc) {
        tempc = (tempf - 32) * 5 / 9;

        return tempc;
    }
}
```

Am a beginner in Java, can't figure out why the code is wrong...

Comment: Ok, let us know what is wrong first.

Comment: `tempc = ftoc(tempf, tempc);`

Comment: Where is the problem? What's not working as you expected?

Answer (score 1):

Java is a pass by value language, so `ftoc` can't change the value of the `tempc` variable passed to it. In order for your variable to be updated, you must assign the output of the method to it :

```
tempc = ftoc(tempf, tempc);
```

which means there's no point to pass `tempc` to that method in the first place.

```
public static double ftoc(double tempf) {
    return (tempf - 32) * 5 / 9;
}

...

tempc = ftoc(tempf);
```